# IBM DB2 using SSL error: handshake_error/connection reset. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

Tags: java, db2, datasource, keystore, hikaricp

I am using Hikari to connect to DB2 for Z/OS over SSL. The url I am using is structured like the following

```
jdbc:db2://[hostname]:[port]/[location]:sslConnection=true;
```

I have to pass the truststore, truststore password, keystore, and keystore password. This is a JKS file.

The only way I am able to pass the this information and get a successful connection is through the usage of the `System.setPropety("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", [path to truststore])`. I do not want to use the System.setPropety(). I want to use the IBM `sslTrustStoreLocation, sslTrustStorePassword, etc` properties

When I try using sslTrustStoreLocation, sslTrustStorePassword, sslKeyStoreLocation, sslKeyStorePassword the new url looks like the following

```
jdbc:db2://[hostname]:[port]/[location]:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=[absolute_path];sslTrustStorePassword=[password];sslKeyStoreLocation=[absolute_path];sslKeyStorePassword=[password];
```

I also tried keeping the url as

```
jdbc:db2://[hostname]:[port]/[location]:sslConnection=true;
```

and adding the properties (sslTrustStoreLocation, sslTrustStorePassword, sslKeyStoreLocation, sslKeyStorePassword) via Hikari config using addDataSourceProperty()

Additionally I tried using IBM Data Studio and adding a new Database Connection over SSL and got the same error as the other two attempts as shown below

```
[jcc][10512][13714]Failed to create connection. SQLCODE: -4499 SQLSTATE: 08001 Message: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.25.13] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream. Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1). Message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

it alternates between `handshake_failure` and `connection reset`

The pom.xml has the following dependency in case that helps

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
    <version>11.5.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Just to reiterate - I can get the conmnection to work when I use the System.setPropety() function; however, I cannot when I use the sslTrustStoreLocation, sslTrustStorePassword, sslKeyStoreLocation, sslKeyStorePassword which shouls be interchangeable accourding to [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=dsdjsss-configuring-connections-under-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj-use-ssl)

Comment: On the host running Hikari, and Data Studio, Whose jvm / jdk are you using , and which version?

Comment: The jdbc driver version shown in your question is [4.25.13] (which is from Db2 v11.1) , but it is better to use 4.32.28 (= most recent one available now). Separately your connection string should not have `sslKeyStoreLocation=[absolute_path];sslKeyStorePassword=[password];`  (but the other three `sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=/path/to/jks;sslTrustStorePassword=valid_password;` are required.  The docs state these are all valid for Db2-for-Z/OS, and they work for me with Db2-LUW when using the IBM jvm and IBM jdk. There may be more details in the Db2-for-Z/OS diagnostics.

Comment: @mao java corretto 11 (OpenJDK 11) for both my host running hikari and I believe it's the same for data studio. As for the jdbc driver version, I updated to 4.32.28 and adjusted the url so that `sslKeyStoreLocation=[absolute_path];sslKeyStorePassword=[password];` are removed. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps [here](https://ibm.github.io/db2forzosdeveloperextension-about/docs/the-basics/creating-a-database-connection) and saw that I was missing the property: `securityMechanism=18`